# Cannot convert from int to system.collections.generic.icomparer<int>

Tags: c#, list, compilation, foreach, int

New to C# Just wondering what the error is, can't understand the error. No need to correct, just want to know the mistake. 
ERROR:
The best overloaded method match for 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List.BinarySearch(int,System.Collections.Generic.Icomparer)' has some invalid arguments
Argument1: Cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list to int
Argument2: Cannot convert from int to system.collections.generic.icomparer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;enter code here
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LotoNumbers
{
    public partial class FrmLotto : Form
{
    // declare class level variables
    List<int> player = new List<int>(7);
    List<int> computer = new List<int>(6);

    public FrmLotto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // event method to generate player's numbers
    private void btnPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // declare and initalize local variables
        string display = "";

        // reset the winning number label before generating the player's numbers
        lblComputerNumber.Text = "00  00  00  00  00  00";

        // generate unique random numbers
        GenerateRandomNumbers(player);
        player.Sort();
        // build display string
        display = BuildDisplayString(player);

        // display winning number in label
        lblPlayerNumber.Text = display;
    }

    // method to generate computer's random numbers (the 'winning numbers')
    // and determine how many winning numbers
    private void btnComputer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // declare and initalize local variables
        int winCount = 0;
        string display = "";

        // generate unique random numbers
        GenerateRandomNumbers(computer);

        // sort the array in ascending order
        computer.Sort();

        // build display string
        display = BuildDisplayString(computer);

        // display winning number in label
        lblComputerNumber.Text = display;

        // determine if this number matches any of the players numbers
        winCount = CompareTwoList(player, computer);

        // display the total winning numbers
        lblMatching.Text = winCount.ToString("D2");
    }

    private void GenerateRandomNumbers(List<int> numberList)
    {


        Random lucky = new Random();

        // generate unique random numbers
        for (int index = 0; index < numberList.Capacity; index++)
        {
            int temp = lucky.Next(1, 50);
            if (numberList.IndexOf(temp) < 0)
            {
                numberList.Add(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                index--;
            }
        }

    }

    private string BuildDisplayString(List<int> numberList)
    {
        // declare method variable
        string display = "  ";

        // loop through the array and build a display string
        foreach (int number in numberList)
            display += number.ToString("D2") + "  ";

        // return display string
        return display;
    }

    private int CompareTwoList(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
    {
        // declare method variable
        int numberMatching = 0;

        // loop through each element in the first array looking for a match in the second array
        foreach (int value in list1)
        {
            if (player.BinarySearch(list2, value) >= 0)
                numberMatching++;  // a matching value is found
        }

        return numberMatching;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It would have helped if you'd  just have posted the relevant part and if you'd mentioned the line where the error was raised.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want:

```
if (list2.BinarySearch(value) >= 0)
    numberMatching++;  // a matching value is found
```

You are calling [List<int>.BinarySearch(int, IComparer<int>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx) at the moment. Since `value` is an `int` you are getting a type error.

Note you can also do:

```
int numberMatching = list2.Intersect(list1).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload for `List<int>.BinarySearch()` which accepts a `List<int>` and `int` as the parameters. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx)

You need to use `player.BinarySearch(value)`